# target HTML option label instead of its value in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to target the option label instead of its value in a PHP page.

I know that PHP is server side and it could be difficult to target the option label but is there a work around for this?

the code i am using is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
        "css/mainstyle_css.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
        "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>
          title
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <select name="myList" id="myList" class="myList">
        <optgroup label="list 1">
    <option value="music/one" label="techno">techno</option>
    <option value="music/two" label="rock">rock</option>

    </optgroup>
      </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Search"/>

    </form>

     <?php echo $myList; ?>



    </body>

</html>
```

with the code above I get the music/one and music/two echo-ed on the php page. what i need to do is to echo their labels which are "techno" and "rock".

could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: you can change options like this `<option value="techno" label="techno">techno</option>`

Comment: Why do you want to parse HTML using PHP on the server? This makes no sense.

Comment: sorry this is off topic, but why are you still using that doctype? I thought we all switched to <!DOCTYPE html>.. you know for consistency.

Comment: @Akam, no I cannot do that. the values should stay as they are.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something here.  Where are you setting $myList?

Comment: @Diodeus, why doesn't it make sense?!

Comment: Because things like this are typically done on the client, using JavaScript.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, there is piece of php code at the beginning of the page that was not necessary to post for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @Diodeus, you are wrong. there are some instances that you need to do it server side. in my case i need to do it server side because a html page gets created from the dynamic php page. and especial characters  like music"/"one.html are not allowed. so i need it to be techno.html and rock.html etc.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx I got you, but for what purpose the `value` attribute for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$options = array();
$options["music/one"] = "techno";
$options["music/two"] = "rock";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainstyle_css.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <select name="myList" id="myList" class="myList">
                <optgroup label="list 1">
                    <?php
                    foreach($options as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" label="'. $value .'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
        <?php echo $options[$_POST['myList']]; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay this works in a way. BUT how about if there are 100's of options on the page? do I have to add $options["music/three"] = "somename"; $options["music/four"] = "somename"; for every single one? Or is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
    "css/mainstyle_css.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
    "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
      title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form method="post" action="a.php">
  <select name="myList" id="myList" class="myList">
    <optgroup label="list 1">
<?php
  foreach($options as $key => $value)
                {
                    echo "<option value='{$key}' label='{$value}'>{$value}</option>"; // this will fill all your values in option field via loop
                }
                ?>
<option value="music/one" label="techno">techno</option>  // you can also do it this way manually as u did.
<option value="music/two" label="rock">rock</option>

</optgroup>
  </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Search"/>

</form>
 </body>

</html>

// below codeshould be in a.php

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo $_POST['myList']; 
}
?>
```